# Is memcpy() safe when copy some content larger than dst?

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

Is it safe when the `request_token.size()` is larger than `LEN`?

```
char dst[LEN];
memcpy(dst, request_token.c_str(), request_token.size());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not safe; you'll cause a buffer overflow. The reason is, `memcpy` has no way to know the size of your target buffer, other than the size you pass in the third argument.

Answer (score 1):

No, definitely not, that will lead to buffer overrun and trigger undefined behavior which will lead to all sorts of bad things, included but not limited to data corruption and program crashing.

Comment: "coppuprtion"? Did the nasal demons affect your writing too? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dswaw1wk(VS.80).aspx

Use memcpy_s(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dswaw1wk(VS.80).aspx

Comment: memcpy_s is nonstandard and not portable. Just make sure you don't copy more than the buffer size.

Comment: It's also a crutch for people who have no right coding in C. If you don't want to learn how to use the tools properly, go back to BASIC :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, you will end up in trying to write to invalid memory locations which causes undefined behavior.